# Download this form data to XML

Tags: php, xml, forms

A simple form with some data, like:

- Name
- Place
- Price

The page with the form will be loaded with specific link: mywebsite.it/data2xml.php or mywebsite.it/data2xml.xml.

Edit: here's my form page:

```
<form method=post action="download.php">  
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" />  
<br />  
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />  
<br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

here's the link to the page http://ts89.altervista.org/downloads/form2xml.php

Comment: What have you got so far? Paste some formatted code into your question, and someone will help `:)`. Also, do you want to consume XML, or generate it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "if the form is XML" - the form will always give you GET/POST parameters, which your PHP will need to turn into XML. OK, well please give this a go first; set up your form to point to data2xml.php, and then the easy way is to echo your XML document as a simple string, containing the parameters you've got from your form.

Comment: (Incidentally, it is better to edit your question itself with updates, rather than trying to squash code into comment boxes!)

Comment: @halfer I updated the question...you can see the code in the form page. Now I have to write the "download.php" page for loading data from "form2xml.php" and download or display in XML format

Comment: I think no one still knows what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!-- form.html -->
<form method=post action="download.php">  
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" />  
<br />  
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />  
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

Then you need something to create the XML, thus:

```
<?php
// download.php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

echo "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<root>
    <firstname>{$firstname}</firstname>
    <lastname>{$lastname}</lastname>
</root>
";
```

This is *very* basic - you may wish to check the values of the post elements. Also, you don't need your second `<form>`, as far as I can tell. I would recommend doing some tutorials on PHP, and get a book on it - there's only so much you can learn without some solid, self-directed study.